# Sum of Product of Numbers taken two at a time

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So the question is

Find the Sum of Product taken two at a time of of numbers  $1,2,2^2,2^3...2^{n-2},2^{n-1}$

My approach was to create a double summation like this $y=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^i\cdot2^j$ but the answer comes out to be wrong.

What's wrong with my approach?

Edit:

My answer comes out to be $(2^{n-1}-1)^2$ however my book mentions the answer as $\frac{1}{3}2^{2n}-2^n-\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: You count things like $1\times 2^1$ twice.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: Yes.  As this is an error I make all the time, it wasn't hard to spot.

Comment: Easier to consider how the sum is changed when you add $2^n$ to the set, perhaps